# How to change the icon Gmaps.js uses in Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

How can I use the latest version of [GMaps.js](http://hpneo.github.com/gmaps/) to change the pin icon I set in code?

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
$('input[name="Address"]').blur(function () {
    GMaps.geocode({
        address: $('input[name="Address"]').val(),
        callback: function (results, status) {
            if (status == 'OK') {
                var latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
                map.setCenter(latlng.lat(), latlng.lng());
                map.addMarker({
                    lat: latlng.lat(),
                    lng: latlng.lng(),
                    icon: {
                        image: "http://i.imgur.com/12312.png"
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

When running this script, the following errors flare up in Firebug's console:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:17680/Account/undefined"

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:17680/Account/undefined"
```

I don't understand why it's trying to HTTP GET that URL since I've never invoked it anywhere in the code.

Comment: @RASG: I already answered my question, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing the icon on a marker is quite simple.

If you read the [documentation](http://hpneo.github.com/gmaps/documentation.html#GMaps-createMarker), notice it says:

> Also, createMarker accepts any option defined in google.maps.MarkerOptions 
>   and any marker event defined in google.maps.Marker ('Events' section).

And if you read the Google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions), it's just a matter of calling:

```
icon: "some-url-here"
```

---

In my case it was:

```
$('input[name="Address"]').blur(function () {
    GMaps.geocode({
        address: $('input[name="Address"]').val(),
        callback: function (results, status) {
            if (status == 'OK') {
                var latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
                map.setCenter(latlng.lat(), latlng.lng());
                map.addMarker({
                    lat: latlng.lat(),
                    lng: latlng.lng(),
                    icon: "/images/mapicon.png"
                });

                $('input[name="Longitude"]').val(latlng.lng());
                $('input[name="Latitude"]').val(latlng.lat());
            }
        }
    });
});
```